# Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to set an git/SSH command *only* for use with background fetches?

Tags: git, authentication, visual-studio-code, ssh

Here's the context for this:

VS Code on Mac v 1.68.1, installed via Homebrew, macOS 12.4, remote end is FreeBSD 12.3 (which includes openSSH 7.9)

I have background git fetching turned on.  When I log in, it's either with GSSAPI Authentication (which requires that I `kinit` first) OR with a password, which we allow on our VPN (i.e. the world cannot brute force us).

So, from a shell, I can type "git pull" and be fine, I'll get prompted for a password if I don't have an active Kerberos ticket.  But git background fetches cause sshd/ssh to prompt for a password, that cannot be displayed to me.

This feels like a bug, and it feels like anything "background" should basically set `-o PasswordAuthentication=No` (and similar, like `-o ChallengeResponseAuthentication`) to ssh.

This trips up our IDS as it looks like someone is trying to brute force my login.

Here are the ways forward I see:

- Just turning off background fetching for this repo, if that's even possible.  (It seems I have this turned on at the "User" level, which overrides anything else.)
- Allowing the background fetch to Specify its own ssh command (this option doesn't exist yet)
- Similarly, allowing background fetch to set its own environment variables.
- Using some kind of global ssh wrapper that sees how the command is being called. (Feels Hacky)
- Giving background-fetch some kind of test to see if auth is likely to succeed (in my case this would be running `klist`).
- Setting some kind of per-repo ssh command override (i.e. in a `.git/config`) that basically turns off any kind of interactive authentication.  (Again, I like being able to use my password when it's presented as an option, so killing it globally is not a preference).

If the answer here is "I should open a feature request with VS Code, then so be it" but there may be some deep `git` or VS Code magic I haven't discovered for exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding HTTPS, check forst if git config --global credential.manager is set: it should be able to cache your credentials, allowing you to *not* enter a password every time.

For SSH, check if your private key is passphrase protected: you would have to deal with ssh-agent if it is.

And see if `git config --global url.git@github.com:.insteadOf https://github.com/` would help Git consider SSH URL even if HTTPS ones are used.
Replace `github.com` by the remote domain you are using.

Comment: It’s SSH, with interactive password authentication (kerberos backend), or GSSAPI, which expires.  GSSAPI is *like* pubkey auth in that it’s passwordless, but there’s no agent.

Comment: @Gushi OK. I am not familiar with GSSAPI (which supposed to have been [activated on the remote sshd_config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-kerberos-configuration-users.html#emr-kerberos-ssh-config=)). But I maintain my `git config insteadOf` option, to make sure you are using only one protocol consistently.

Comment: I know how SSH works.  I know how auth works.  My question was not about git *or* ssh, it was about Visual Studio Code.  Does it set some special environment variable when doing a background fetch, for example?  Is there a way to tell it "if this condition is set, do not do a background fetch".

Comment: @Gushi "Does it set some special environment variable when doing a background fetch,": not that I know of, no.